# Python logging in multiple modules

Tags: python, logging

I want to write a logger which I can use in multiple modules. I must be able to enable and disable it from one place. And it must be reusable.

Following is the scenario.
switch_module.py

```
class Brocade(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, username, password):
        ...

    def connect(self):
        ...
    def disconnect(self):
        ...
    def switch_show(self):
        ...
```

switch_module_library.py

```
import switch_module

class Keyword_Mapper(object):
    def __init__(self, keyword_to_execute):
        self._brocade_object = switch_module.Brocade(ip, username, password)
        ...
    def map_keyword_to_command(self)
        ...
```

application_gui.py

```
class GUI:
    # I can open a file containing keyword for brocade switch
    # in this GUI in a tab and tree widget(it uses PyQt which I don't know)
    # Each tab is a QThread and there could be multiple tabs

    # Each tab is accompanied by an execute button.
    # On pressing exeute it will read the string/keywords from the file
    # and create an object of keyword_Mapper class and call
    # map_key_word_to_command method, execute the command on brocade
    # switch and log the results. Current I am logging the result
    # only from the Keyword_Mapper class.
```

Problem I have is how to write a logger which could be enabled and disabled at will
and it must log to one file as well as console from all three modules.

I tried writing global logger in **int**.py and then importing it in all three modules
and had to give a common name so that they log to the same file, but then
ran into trouble since there is multi-threading and later created logger to
log to a file which has thread-id in its name so that I can have each log
per thread.

What if I am required to log to different file rather than the same file?

I have gone through python logging documentation but am unable to get a clear picture
about writing a proper logging system which could be reused.

I have gone through this link
[Is it better to use root logger or named logger in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231809/is-it-better-to-use-root-logger-or-named-logger-in-python)

but due to the GUI created by someone other than me using PyQt and multi-threading I am unable to get my head around logging here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my project I only use a root logger (I dont have the time to create named loggers, even if it would be nice). So if you don't want to use a named logger, here is a quick solution:

I created a function to set up logger quickly:

```
import logging

def initLogger(level=logging.DEBUG):
    if level == logging.DEBUG:
        # Display more stuff when in a debug mode
        logging.basicConfig(
            format='%(levelname)s-%(module)s:%(lineno)d-%(funcName)s: %(message)s',
            level=level)
    else:
        # Display less stuff for info mode
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=level)
```

I created a package for it so that I can import it anywhere.

Then, in my top level I have:

```
import LoggingTools
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure logger
    LoggingTools.initLogger(logging.DEBUG)
    #LoggingTools.initLogger(logging.INFO)
```

Depending if I am debugging or not, I using the corresponding statement.

Then in each other files, I just use the logging:

```
import logging
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        logging.debug("Debug message")
        logging.info("Info message")
```