# Using python's logging package, how to write to different log files using same Logger

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have two files names "parent" and "child". There are no classes, just two files with functions and `if __name__ == "__main__"` statements. Both files in their main functions have a function that creates a logger object with a `TimedRotatingFileHandler` using `logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')`, and then returns logger. That function is shown below:

```
def setupLogFile():
    LOG_FILE_NAME = "/path/to/pyrpc.log"
    logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE_NAME, when="midnight")
    logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s |%(levelname)s|: %(message)s')
    logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
    logger.addHandler(logHandler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger
```

Many functions in both files contain calls such as

```
logger.info("log something important")
```

Let's call one of these functions "funcA()". My question is, if parent imports child, and then somewhere in parent there is a line that runs

```
child.funcA()
```

How do I make it so that the "logger.info("log something important")" line within funcA() knows to use the logger object created in the main function of parent?

Right now I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testblockadder.py", line 57, in <module>
      testInitialDBData(topBlockHeight)
   File "testblockadder.py", line 33, in testInitialDBData
      testpyrpc.testBlock(block, blkHeight)
   File "/path/to/pyrpc.py", line 46, in testBlock
      logger.info("log something important")
NameError: global name 'logger' is not defined
```

I have read about declaring the logger at the module level using

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

But it seems like this always uses `logging.basicConfig()`, which I'm fairly certain means I have to have log to the same file everytime. The functions that run exclusively in parent log to a different file than that of funcA(). It'd be okay if any of the code I ran in parent logged to the same log file, but I need the logs in that file to be able to say which file that log was called in (i.e. whether it came from parent or child).

EDIT: I have managed to use the tips from this SO post [difference in logging mechanism: API and application(python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630926/difference-in-logging-mechanism-api-and-applicationpython/2631396#2631396) to get the logging that I needed. However I have a lingering question regarding this type of setup. I've used `basicConfig` to set the `formatter` and logging location. Is there a way to change the default `StreamHandler` that `basicConfig` sets up for me to instead me a `TimedRotatingFileHandler`? That way I don't log everything to one file for all time.